# Get value of a counter

Tags: macros, counters

Consider this code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\newcounter{counterA}
\newcounter{counterB}
\begin{document}
...
\setcounter{counterA}{2}
\setcounter{counterB}{3}
\addtocounter{counterB}{counterA}
\end{document}
```

When I compile I get the following error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   c
l.8 \addtocounter{counterB}{counterA}
```

How to add the value in counterA to counterB?

Comment: `\addtocounter{counterB}{\value{counterA}}`

Comment: In case that this is related to your page counter problem: due to the asynchronic page building of tex, the page counter is often not reliable in the text body.

Comment: In case Ulrike's hunch is right, you may be interested in https://texfaq.org/FAQ-wrongpn

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access the *value* of a counter for arithmetic or other situations where LaTeX expects a number with `\value{<countername>}`, so

```
\addtocounter{counterB}{\value{counterA}}
```

should be what you are looking for.

You would use `\the<countername>` to *print* (a representation of) the value.

```
\thecounterB
```

Gives

> 5

in the example.

In rare situations or when you define `\the<countername>` you may have to use

```
\arabic{<countername>}
\roman{<countername>}
\Roman{<countername>}
\alph{<countername>}
\Alph{<countername>}
```

to force a particular printed representation.